# SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. !! - How to build Python/C++ package locally and distribution wheel

Tags: python-3.x, build, setuptools, cpython, python-wheel

I have Python/C++ project, where I am using some C++ functions wrapped in Python and provided in Python as a library. The following shows the directory structure:

```
.
├── examples
│   └── test_file1.py
├── include
│   ├── proj1_headers
│   └── proj2_headers
├── LICENSE.md
├── mylib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── mylib.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── file1.cc
```

So, the C++ headers are under the `include` directory. To build the project **locally** (*that is, not installing it to my Python environment*) I am using the following command:

```
python setup.py develop
```

The convenience that this method gives me is the following - I can simply move the `mylib*` files/directories to my examples directory, where in my example Python file I can simply do `import mylib`. Nothing is installed to my environment which remains clean.

Although, this command builds the desired library as `mylib*` under the project root, it throws the following warning:

```
/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py39env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer, pypa/build or
        other standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  easy_install.initialize_options(self)
/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py39env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer, pypa/build or
        other standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
```

My question regarding the above has two parts:

1. How can I build using the new method, *locally*, that is without actually installing to my Python environment? (the develop option in the setup method)
2. How to create a distributable `*.whl` file for my library?